# Office 2013 - Excel function

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I am using excel 2013
In Column 3 I have a list of airline names
In Column P I have percent for each carriers data...show as 60.047% i
I would like to have ever number >=1* to highlight the adjacent Airline name in Column C

Comment: Please add an example to your question.  It really isn't understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a conditional format should work.  Highlight Column C, click on Conditional Formatting on the ribbon then New Rule, and Use a Formula...  The formula "=or($P1>=1)" should work.

Comment: I got it to work late last night but I could not get it work with>=1 but rather with >=0.01    I suspect that this was because the column was formatted for percentage. Thaks

Comment: Failed to consider the formatting.  You're right.  Glad I could help.